# MS Teams support for Ultra-Wide (21:9) monitors

Tags: microsoft-teams, aspect-ratio, multiple-monitors

I would like to switch to single Ultra-Wide monitor (21:9 ratio) instead of having few smaller monitors. During my work I often present using MS Teams but when sharing the whole desktop (I'm switching between many applications, so I can't share a single window) the view on other people monitors is re-scaled so much that it becomes unreadable. See this video to see what I mean:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9U6XqaM4cg

There is some third party tool which might help with this issue a little, but this is just a workaround:
https://github.com/michiproep/ScreenshareHelper

Many people use MS PowerToys to better utilize Ultra-Wide monitors:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

When using MS PowerToys it is possible to define "Fancy Zones", so for example it is possible to define a screen zone which has "popular" 16:9 aspect ratio. Unfortunately MS Teams are not recognizing this feature.

My idea is to add to MS Teams possibility to detect if user is using MS PowerToys Fancy Zones and to let him/her select specific zone for sharing. This will let me use MS Teams effectively on Ultra-Wide monitor. I see that there are many questions related to this, so I think a lot of users would benefit from this solution.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

MS Teams doesn´t share the screen of monitor ultrawide corretly yet. You see the image very small. In my case, I have a Samsung LC49RG90SSRXEN 49" monitor and I cannot share correclty the screen.

I have proven two workaround, for me, the first is a better option.

First workaround, use OBS and share with Team the window called 'Projector with window(preview)' that create OBS when you capture the screen, that allows to you share many applications in a particular region of your screen.

[image: Projector with window(preview)]

In OBS, we create a source of screen capture and choose the screen we want to share in Teams.

[image]

If we want to select a particular region of the screen, we can change the size and region of the capture, we only have to click in the corner of the capture and move, if we press 'alt' while we are clicking in the corner change the region of the capture.

[image]

When we have the region and size that we want, we click left button on the capture and choose 'Projector with window(preview)', this window will be shared in Teams.

[image: 'Projector with window(preview)']

In Teams, we select the windows 'Projector with window(preview)' to share.

[image]

In this video, I reproduce the before steps.

[Share a region of your screen using a ultrawide monitor in Teams](https://youtu.be/-ouWP9K1KTg)

Second workaround, to use  PIP/PBP (Picture by Picture) function of the monitor, that allow to split the screen in half, and display in one part the output video of the laptop and in the other part the output video of the XBOX. It is not necessary connect two devices, if you connect only one, the screen will be split in half, and the other part of the screen will display black. Now, you can share this screen in half in teams that has a minor size, and it will be display correctly. In this link you can see how to active the BPM function in a samsung monitor.

[How to split screen into two desktops on Samsung 49 inch ultrawide monitor - LC49HG90DMUXEN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIp7bDMaIU4)

Maybe, in the future teams will be develop a feature for ultrawide monitor.

Comment: Hello, today it is still the best answer I’ve found. Thanks so much